# React component css not being set properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I have a universal React application based off of https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

In one of my components I am trying to implement react-select https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

I copied and pasted the CSS from the example directory into my scss file and when I pull up the modal that is supposed to have the select, it's just a squished, tiny, input field with no styling on it at all. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Modal.scss';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/lib/select-field';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/lib/checkbox';
import ActionFavorite from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/favorite';
import ActionFavoriteBorder from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/favorite-border';
import TextInput from '../UI/TextInput';
import Button from '../UI/Button';
import Select from 'react-select';

class AddQuestionModal extends Component {    

    createQuestion = () => {
        this.props.createQuestion();
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.props.close();
    }

    changeText = (val) => {
        this.props.changeText(val);
    }

    changeAnswer = (val) => {
        this.props.changeAnswer(val);
    }

    techSelectChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.props.techSelectChange(value);
    }

    updateTags = (val) => {
        this.props.updateTags(val);
    }


    levelSelectChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.props.levelSelectChange(value);
    }

    render() {
        let multiLine = true;
        return (
            <Modal
                isOpen={this.props.open}
                onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>

                <h2>New Question</h2>
                <TextInput
                    hintText="Question"
                    change={this.changeText}
                    multiLine = {true}
                    default = {this.props.question.text}
                />
                <TextInput
                    hintText="Answer"
                    change={this.changeAnswer}
                    multiLine = {true}
                    default = {this.props.question.answer}
                />
                <div>
                    <SelectField
                        value={this.props.question.tech}
                        onChange={this.techSelectChange}
                        floatingLabelText="Technology">
                        <MenuItem value={"JavaScript"} primaryText="JavaScript"/>
                        <MenuItem value={"Java"} primaryText="Java"/>
                        <MenuItem value={"C#"} primaryText="C#"/>
                        <MenuItem value={".NET"} primaryText=".NET"/>
                        <MenuItem value={"iOS"} primaryText="iOS"/>
                    </SelectField>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <SelectField
                        value={this.props.question.level}
                        onChange={this.levelSelectChange}
                        floatingLabelText="Difficulty">
                        <MenuItem value={"Beginner"} primaryText="Beginner"/>
                        <MenuItem value={"Intermediate"} primaryText="Intermediate"/>
                        <MenuItem value={"Advanced"} primaryText="Advanced"/>
                        <MenuItem value={"Expert"} primaryText="Expert"/>
                    </SelectField>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Select
                        name="tags"
                        options={this.props.question.tags}
                        onChange={this.updateTags}
                        multi={true}
                        allowCreate={true}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className='buttonDiv'>
                    <Button label='Cancel'
                        disabled={false}
                        onSubmit={this.closeModal}
                    />
                    <Button label='Create Question'
                        disabled={false}
                        onSubmit={this.createQuestion}
                    />
                </div>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

AddQuestionModal.propTypes = {
    open : PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    close : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    question : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    createQuestion : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    changeText : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    changeAnswer : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    techSelectChange : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    levelSelectChange : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    updateTags : PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(AddQuestionModal, s);
```

'./Modal.scss'; is the stylesheet that is copied directly from the github example.

There are no css options being applied to that field when I look in the dev tools.

[image: screenshot of modal]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what it looks like or an example? Are you saying the modal is squished or the select field? Can you look in the browser which styles are being applied and from what?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem the first time I used it.
You need to import the css file from `react-select`.

Example:

```
require('../../node_modules/react-select/dist/react-select.min.css')
```

Comment: I have this style sheet copied into modal.scss and it doesn't affect the select

Comment: @erichardson30 is this https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/dist/example.css the css file u copied?

Comment: Copied that one as well as the css file in the react-select npm module

Comment: Do you use webpack? if so are u using the css-loader?

Comment: `{
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'isomorphic-style-loader',
          `css-loader?${DEBUG ? 'sourceMap&' : 'minimize&'}modules&localIdentName=` +
          `${DEBUG ? '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]' : '[hash:base64:4]'}`,
        ],
      },` is in my webpack config

Comment: woow, what a config...
Could u try something simpler? like
`{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?root=.' },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108534/discussion-between-andre-junges-and-erichardson30).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are not applying any styles to the `<SelectField />`. Try adding `className = { s.my-class-name }`as a property to the select field.

Comment: This is handled within the SelectField component.

Comment: What classes are you expecting to be applied to what elements? At the moment what is being applied to those?

Comment: Select Select--multi is-searchable Select-control Select-placeholder Select-input Select-arrow-zone are all there

Comment: So all the expected classes are being applied? Are you 100% sure the select fields are getting any data or that nothing is causing an error elsewhere? select fields will sometimes look like that if they have no data to display

Comment: All classnames are there but there are no styles on the elements